# Access queries running slow

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an application with the front end in Access 2007 (Access 2000 file) with the backend on SQL Server 2008. The application has been running for two years now and I have noticed that on some PCs the queries are taking forever to run while on others it runs quite fast. Each PC has its own file of Access, so they don't share the file.

Simple queries with just one table take a long time to run. The biggest table has 578,000 records.

Sometimes it takes 10 seconds to load a simple table with just 6 records. We are on a gigabit network.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at your Indexing? Do you have Primary/Foreign Key relationships defined?

Comment: I have not changed anything in the database for the past year. I just noticed recently that the queries are running slow except on the server where the SQL Server is also on. It IS on a different domain.

Comment: So lets say a week ago it ran "fast".  What changed. You upgraded from SQL Server? Your network was upgraded?  What things are in motion here?

Comment: The server was upgraded from SQL Server 2005 to 2008. I can't really say exactly at what point it has slowed down, but it seems like a communication problem.

Comment: I do have Primary Keys on all my tables and some foreign keys. Can I add some indexes to speed up some really slow queries?

Comment: You can add indexes, but they have to be carfully considered. I'm not sure how Access optimizes queries into SQL, but try recreting the queries in SSMS and seeing what the execution plan (CTRL+M) is like. It may even suggest some indexes for you, but be careful -- it's not always right. And don't overdo it.

Comment: If I run the Pass-Through Query SELECT getdate() As DateTime; on my PC it takes about 15 seconds to execute, while if I run it on the server which has SQL Server 2008 running it takes about a second.

Comment: Can you post an example slow-running query?

Comment: Try that SELECT query using `osql` from a command window.  For windows auth the command is:  `osql -S yourdbservername -E -Q "SELECT getdate() as DateTime;"`  For SQL server auth the command is:  `osql -S yourdbservername -U SQLServerUsername -P password -Q "SELECT getdate() as DateTime;"`

Comment: That will help narrow down whether the problem is with Access or strictly network related.

Comment: [SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
connection to SQL Server [2].
[SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired
[SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error
has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server
Books Online.

Comment: Can't seem to connect with trusted connection and SQL user an pass

Comment: That may or may not be related to the other problems you are having.  I think it would be immensely useful to know whether the extra 15 seconds for executing that query are coming from the network or access.  On the other hand, I don't want you to waste a lot of time getting this to work if it won't fix your problem.  I'd explore other possibilities but if you run up against a wall, I'd come back and try to get osql working (maybe open a new question on SO).

Comment: Have you installed the SQL Server ODBC native client and used it for your connect strings? If not, you should. Certainly with the new SQL Server, you need to delete and recreate all your linked tables. This sounds like the typical outdated metadata problem in linked tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the linked tables in Access and added them again. This seemed to improve the query times considerably.

Which Driver is better to connect to SQL Server 2008: SQL Server Native Client 10.0 v.2007.100.2531.00 or SQL Server v. 2000.85.1132.00

The ODBC Driver connection that I used is SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 03.85.1132

Comment: I would use the SQL Server Native client 10.0. That's the newest one, and is designed to take advantage of the new features in 2008. It's also faster than any other ODBC driver I've ever used with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

do the pcs that take forever to run have less memory than the speedy ones?

also check the versions of the ODBC drivers on the clients.

Answer (score 1):

SET EXPLAIN ON... to see the overhead involved in the queries.

Try re-building your indexes and use clustering where appropiate to group the rows by customer id or whatever column your app requires. If this doesn't help, then the problem could be that SQL'08 has more overhead than '05 and you may need to increase memory or more CPU power.

Answer (score 0):

That could be caused by users joining a local table with a table on SQL Server.

Joining a local table with an SQL Server table forces Access to **retrieve the entire SQL Server table** and perform the join on the local computer.

We have had similar *problems* in the past.

Comment: I haven't changed anything on the database for the past year, and there are no running local tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating statistics on the SQl server.